# How to ping from vmware to anthor with linux?

Tags: linux, laptop, vmware, ping

I don't have an IP address, how to now it! 
I am working on my project and need to know how to ping between two VM's, I use Linux for them. Jest I need the steps to ping.

Comment: Please provide more details about the scenario - this isn't really possible to answer and is extremely highly dependent on how you've configured VMWare's networking capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

To ping from a linux command line:

ping -c 4 www.google.com

This will ping google 4 times and display results like:

## ping -c 4 www.google.com

PING www.google.com (172.217.12.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga25s62-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=47.2 ms
64 bytes from lga25s62-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=43.5 ms
64 bytes from lga25s62-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.164): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=44.8 ms
64 bytes from lga25s62-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.12.164): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=47.4 ms

To determine the IP address on a linux machine type: ifconfig

Look for the inet: addr.